# Term for sum, difference, product, quotient

Tags: terminology

Feel free to let me know if this is better suited for:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/
- https://stackoverflow.com/

That said, I'm wondering if there's a math term for the nature of "sum", "difference", "product", and "quotient".

Now these are obviously the results of specific operations (i.e. sum can only be produced by an addition operation), however is there a math term more appropriate than how I just used "results"?

Another way to put it, say I were building an array of these terms, what would the variable name be?

```
const someMathTerm = ['SUM', 'DIFF, 'PROD', 'QUOT'];
```

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) "The values combined are called operands, arguments, or inputs, and the value produced is called the **value**, **result**, or **output**."  I don't know of any technical word beyond these.  Of course you could make one up.  For instance, because "quotient" is the special name for the result of division, maybe "operant" should be the name for the result of an arbitrary binary operation.

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks! I think for my needs my best bet is to just suffix your above terms with `type` (`resultType` or `outputType`), since you're right, there doesn't appear to be a more technical term. I always like checking on these little things however. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `binaryOperationResult`?

Addition, subtraction, etc., are all binary operations: *A -OPERATION- B*.

Then you can add `ROOT`, `RMDR`, ...

(I sense that you want something more meaningful than `value`, `result`, etc., as those tend to be overused and six months later you're asking yourself as you read your code, "What kind of value?  Result of what?")

Comment: I like it! Much more descriptive.